# How to disable (deactivate ) log in Spoon?

Tags: java, logging, inria-spoon

I was wondering how can I deactivate log in [Spoon](https://github.com/INRIA/spoon) (library for analyzing and transforming Java source code)?

For example, I want to disable debug log messages. However, I do not know how to set log to Info (log.setLevel(Level.INFO);)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to access the environment of your Spoon launcher and to use the `setLevel` method.

```java
final Launcher launcher = new Launcher();
final Environment env = launcher.getEnvironment();
...
env.setLevel("OFF");
// Then apply your code analysis
```

As explained by the JavaDoc:

> `setLevel(String level)`: Sets the level of loggers asked by the user.

The different levels are (for the version 7.5.0):
"OFF", "FATAL", "ERROR", "WARN", "INFO", "DEBUG", "TRACE", "ALL".
They are the levels provided by the Apache log4j  library.

http://spoon.gforge.inria.fr/mvnsites/spoon-core/apidocs/spoon/compiler/Environment.html